# The constructor in this code is not good. Can someone help me to manage this code?

Tags: delphi

I have a project and two units and main program 
first unit is here it is the main problem the constructor of this class:

```
unit dl_tPA_MailJournal;

interface
uses
  Windows,
  Generics.Collections,
  SysUtils,
  uInterfaces;
  type
    TtPA_MailJournal = class(TInterfacedObject ,ITable)
      public
      function GetanQId: integer;
      procedure SetanQId(const Value: integer);
      function GetadDate: TDateTime;
      procedure SetadDate(const Value: TDateTime);

      function toList: TList<string>;

      constructor Create(aId : Integer; aDate : TDateTime);


      private
      property anQId : integer read GetanQId write SetanQId;
      property adDate : TDateTime read GetadDate write SetadDate;


    end;

implementation

{ TtPA_MailJournal }

constructor TtPA_MailJournal.Create(aId : Integer; aDate : TDateTime);
begin
  SetanQId(aId);
  SetadDate(aDate);
end;

function TtPA_MailJournal.GetadDate: TDateTime;
begin
  Result := adDate;
end;

function TtPA_MailJournal.GetanQId: integer;
begin
  Result := anQId ;
end;

procedure TtPA_MailJournal.SetadDate(const Value: TDateTime);
begin
  adDate := Value;
end;

procedure TtPA_MailJournal.SetanQId(const Value: integer);
begin
  anQId := Value;
end;
function TtPA_MailJournal.toList: TList<string>;
var aListTable: TList<TtPA_MailJournal>;
var aTable: TtPA_MailJournal;
var aListString: TList<String>;
begin
  aTable.Create(1,now);
  aListTable.Add(aTable);
  aTable.Create(2,now);
  aListTable.Add(aTable);
  aListString.Add(aListTable.ToString);

  Result := aListString;
end;
end.
```

Second unit is an interface it is not much to see here

```
unit uInterfaces; 

interface
uses Generics.Collections;
type

  ITable = Interface
  ['{6CED8DCE-9CC7-491F-8D93-996BE8E4D388}']
    function toList: TList<String>;
    End;

implementation

end.
```

The main class, here I want to get stringlist generics and to put into a grid :

```
unit MainUnit;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
  dl_tPA_MailJournal,uInterfaces, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  Generics.Collections, Vcl.Grids;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    StringGrid1: TStringGrid;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;


implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var MyTable: TtPA_MailJournal;
    MyList: TList<String>;
    AStringList: TStrings;
    StrDate : string;
    Fmt: TFormatSettings;
begin

    //fmt.ShortDateFormat:='dd/mm/yyyy';
   // fmt.DateSeparator  :='/';
   // StrDate:='23/02/2011' ;


    MyTable := TtPA_MailJournal.Create(1,now);       //strtodate(strdate,fmt)

    MyList := MyTable.toList;

     AStringList := TStringList.Create;
     AStringList.Add(MyList.ToString);
     StringGrid1.Cols[1].Add(MyList.ToString);
     FreeAndNil(MyTable);




end;

end.
```

When I click the button the program chrashes. When I comment this two
lines of the constructor   SetanQId(aId); and SetadDate(aDate); it is ok 
what I am doing wrong can someone tell me how to manage this code to show in grid please.

Comment: You are setting a property value in its own setter which in turn call that setter again, etc.

Comment: I change it to aId := aId;
  aDate := aDate; and now I get Access violation error

Comment: Programming is not a trial error process. The change you've tried would do essentially the same. It would set a value to the property which would call the setter method in which you would set a value to the property which would call the setter... and so on. You've ended up in an endless loop. I don't know what's the purpose of those properties, but from what your getters and setters do I would say you want [properties that will read and write a private field](http://pastebin.com/Rjve1Knp).

Comment: How about trying to understand what you've been told? Nobody likes spoon feeding askers. We're here because we enjoy teaching.

Answer (score 2):

Declaring property does not allocate any storage to that property. It is merely a pointer to where value will be stored. While you can declare getter and setter functions to access the property value, ultimately property value has to be backed up by some field.

```
TtPA_MailJournal = class(TInterfacedObject ,ITable)
public
  FanId: integer;
  FadDate: TDateTime; 
  function GetanQId: integer;
  procedure SetanQId(const Value: integer);
  function GetadDate: TDateTime;
  procedure SetadDate(const Value: TDateTime);

  function toList: TList<string>;

  constructor Create(aId : Integer; aDate : TDateTime);
private
  property anQId : integer read GetanQId write SetanQId;
  property adDate : TDateTime read GetadDate write SetadDate;
end;

function TtPA_MailJournal.GetadDate: TDateTime;
begin
  Result := FadDate;
end;

function TtPA_MailJournal.GetanQId: integer;
begin
  Result := FanQId ;
end;

procedure TtPA_MailJournal.SetadDate(const Value: TDateTime);
begin
  FadDate := Value;
end;

procedure TtPA_MailJournal.SetanQId(const Value: integer);
begin
  FanQId := Value;
end;
```

If you don't have any special need for getter and setter methods you can declare your property to access its storage field directly:

```
  property anQId : integer read FanQId write FanQId;
  property adDate : TDateTime read FadDate write FadDate;
```

Also, having private properties only makes sense when you have some additional logic implemented in getter and/or setter methods. In this particular case they do not make much sense, so you can fully remove property declaration, and use fields directly.

```
constructor TtPA_MailJournal.Create(aId : Integer; aDate : TDateTime);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FanQId := aId;
  FadDate := aDate;
end;
```

---

First you need to initialize Result and aListTable variables. Then you are using constructor in wrong way instead of `aTable.Create(1, now)` you should use `aTable := TtPA_MailJournal.Create(1,now)`

Another issue you have here is that you are mixing object and interface references and thus leaking objects. So you should use `ITable` to store references to your `TtPA_MailJournal` object instances.

```
function TtPA_MailJournal.toList: TList<string>;
var 
  aListTable: TList<ITable>;
  aTable: ITable;
begin
  Result := TList<String>.Create;
  try
    aListTable := TList<ITable>.Create;
    aTable := TtPA_MailJournal.Create(1,now);
    aListTable.Add(aTable);

    aTable := TtPA_MailJournal.Create(2,now);
    aListTable.Add(aTable);
    Result.Add(aListTable.ToString);
  finally
    aListTable.Free;
  end;
end;
```

You should also release your `MyList` object when you are done with it, or it will leak memory.

Comment: Also your code for populating string grid is probably wrong, but since it is not clear how you want to populate it, I will leave that part for you to figure out...

Comment: Private properties make sense especially when the getter and setter do more than read/write the field.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I was talking about private properties in this particular code where getter and setter are not doing anything.

Comment: It's hard to critique those properties because they are so blatantly wrong, as Heartware explained.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have updated my answer to make it more clear when private properties don't make much sense. If you could misinterpret it, so could anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

You are running out of stack space. You set the property by calling

```
SetanQId(aId);
```

which then contains the statement:

```
anQId := Value;
```

Now, anQId is a property, which you have declared should call the SetanQId method on every assignment, so in essence the above statement is translated into

```
SetanQId(Value);
```

which call the SetanQId method, which contains the statement

```
anQId := Value;
```

Now, anQId is a property, which you have declared should call the SetanQId method on every assignment, so in essence the above statement is translated into

```
SetanQId(Value);
```

which call the SetanQId method, which contains the statement

```
anQId := Value;
```

Now, anQId is a property, which you have declared should call the SetanQId method on every assignment, so in essence the above statement is translated into

```
SetanQId(Value);
```

(see where this is going?)

You have the same problem with the getter - it also ends up calling itself ad infinitum.

You need to declare a backing field to hold the property value, and it is *this* backing field you should read and write from your property getters and setters.

One other thing: You should make it a standard practice to always call the parent's Create method from your own. Although it probably doesn't matter in this particular instance, it is - in general - a bad idea to not do so, as there may be code in the parent's constructor that needs to run in order for the object to be functional. So your constructor should be coded as:

```
constructor TtPA_MailJournal.Create(aId : Integer; aDate : TDateTime);
begin
  inherited Create;
  SetanQId(aId);
  SetadDate(aDate);
end;
```

or

```
constructor TtPA_MailJournal.Create(aId : Integer; aDate : TDateTime);
begin
  inherited Create;
  anQId:=aId;
  adDate:=aDate;
end;
```